# What does "is accounted for" in this mean?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

I partially get the idea of the sentence but I'd really want to know the actually meaning of this phrase here. Plus, for that last clause I don't really get its sentence structure as well. Lastly, could you also give me some more example of the sentence using "is accounted for by"?

**In a hydrogen atom consisting of only one proton and one electron, the greatest proportion by weight is accounted for by the proton.**

Thank you!

Comment: The proton accounts for (makes up, ***is***) most ("**the greatest proportion**") of the weight. For stylistic effect, the writer has turned that highlighted "indirect object" into the syntactic *subject* of the passive clause (with "**the proton**" relegated to the syntactic role of "agent").